# Django 404 dilemma

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I have a bug in my 404 setup. I know that because, when I try to reach some page which doesn't exist, I get my server error template. But that templates is useless because it doesn't give me any debug info. In order to get django's debug page, I need to set DEBUG=True in settings file. But if I do that, bug doesn't appear because django doesn't try to access my buggy 404 setup. So what do you guys think?

This is in my root urls file: 
`handler404 = 'portal.blog.views.handlenotfound'` And this is in portal.blog.views.handlenotfound:

```
def handlenotfound(request):
    global common_data
    datas = {
        'tags' : Tag.objects.all(),
        'date_list' : Post.objects.filter(yayinlandi=True).dates("pub_date","year")
    }
    data.update(common_data)
    return render_to_response("404.html",datas)
```

---

Edit:

I guess I also need to return a HttpResponseNotFound right?

Comment: I accepted ftartaggia's answer although isbadawi's answer actually solved my problem, because his answer actually answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to debug this kind of errors, I would either

- temporarily turn the handler into a simple view served by a custom url, so that django's internal mechanisms don't get into the way, or
- (temporarily) wrap the handler code in a try..except block to log any error you may have missed

Anyway, are you sure your handler doesn't get called if DEBUG=true?

Answer (score 2):

`data.update(common_data)` should be `datas.update(common_data)`.

(Incidentally, data is already plural: the singular is datum.)